# Return type deduction into a template parameter

Tags: c++, c++14, c++-concepts, return-type-deduction

Is there a way one can do this?  As far as I know there isn't since the language does not support it but I wanted to confirm

```
template <typename Something>
ConceptCheck<auto> return_something(const Something& something) {
    return process_something(something);
}
```

This would be nice to have in some cases.  For example where one wants to document the concepts supported by a return type (which would otherwise be a simple auto, requiring the reader to go elsewhere looking for information).

If this seems like a decent thing to propose, I would like to propose this to the standard for the future, can someone direct me about to how to do so?  Are return type concepts already in the C++20 standard?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0238r0.html

Answer (score 2):

You can find just about anything you might want to know about the ongoing standardization effort at https://isocpp.org/

Specifically, https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/12/2016-11-post-issaquah-mailing-available lists all of the documents in the most recent mailing, with the text to the current draft of C++17.

I can tell you that Concepts has **not** been accepted into the draft standard at this time. That could change in the next meeting, though.

Comment: @Curious I don't think anyone knows what C++20 will contain at this point, given that C++17 is not quite final.

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted your answer but I will still wait for an answer that addresses the other parts of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function declaration and a trailing return type to do that.
It follows a minimal, working example (C++14):

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename>
struct ConceptCheck {};

template<typename T>
T get_it(ConceptCheck<T>);

ConceptCheck<char> process_something(int) { return {}; }
ConceptCheck<void> process_something(double) { return {}; }

template <typename Something>
auto return_something(const Something& something)
-> ConceptCheck<decltype(get_it(process_something(something)))> {
    return process_something(something);
}

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(return_something(0)), ConceptCheck<char>>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(return_something(0.)), ConceptCheck<void>>::value, "!");
}
```

Well, I admit that `ConceptCheck<auto>` would be nicer than:

```
ConceptCheck<decltype(get_it(process_something(something)))>
```

Anyway, if the goal was to document the return type `ConceptCheck`, no matter what's the actual template parameter, this is a viable solution.

If you don't like the trailing return type or you cannot document it for it's not supported by your documentation tool, you can still use `std::declval` as it follows:

```
template <typename Something>
ConceptCheck<decltype(get_it(process_something(std::declval<Something>())))>
return_something(const Something& something) {
    return process_something(something);
}
```

Or even better:

```
template <typename Something, typename T = decltype(get_it(process_something(std::declval<Something>())))>
ConceptCheck<T>
return_something(const Something& something) {
    return process_something(something);
}
```

The extra template parameter is pretty ugly, but the return type is finally `ConceptCheck<T>`.